# Alter validation of a required field on a particular page

Tags: users

I have set up 2 registration pages on my website.

On one of the registration pages, i want to hide some fields. I can selectively hide the field. But my challenge is that the field is a required field. So when a user tries to register using that form, it throws an error.

Is there a way to selectively alter the validation of the field on one registration page and not the other, so that users can submit the form with out errors?

Comment: How did you hide the field? Did you use CSS, or did you use hook_form_alter()?

Comment: You should do this with hook_form_alter, not CSS (hence Neograph's question). In hook_form_alter, you just switch #required. For more info, look here: https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7.x/#required

Comment: I used CSS as you guessed. Can you pls help with sample code for the hook?